# Why is changing an attribute allowed?

Tags: ruby

I am wondering why Ruby allows us to change a read-only attribute.

```
class Test
  attr_reader :h

  def initialize
    @h = {}
  end
end

t = Test.new
t.h # => {}
t.h['name'] = 'somename'
t.h # => {"name"=>"somename"}
```

Can we forbid a user to do it?

Comment: Try `@h = {}.freeze`

Comment: Also, there's a fundamental misunderstanding here of what is "read-only" with `attr_reader`. It is the __reference__ to `h`, not the __contents__ of `h`.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev in fact, `attr_reader` has absolutely nothing to do with access rights at all. `attr_reader` just a DSL to define `def attr ; @attr; end` instance function.

Comment: @mudasobwa: yeah, noticed the quotes? :)

Comment: Yes, I understand it, understand what attr_reader does..but..anyway..looks weird in the context of attr_reader. With freeze works properly.

Comment: @EduardBondarenko: you have too high expectations for this method. It does much less than you think :)

Comment: With `attr_reader :h` you only get the getter method (`h`), but not the setter (`h=`). So this won't work: `t.h = { 'name' => 'somename' }`. But in your code you're not using `h=`, you're using [Hash's `[]=`](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Hash.html#method-i-5B-5D-3D).

Answer (score 3):

Your `h` field is the reference to the hash, but you're changing the hash itself, not the reference.

Comment: Exactly. That's why this doesn't work: `t.h = { 'name' => 'somename' }`

Answer (score 0):

`h` is read-only. You can't change the value stored in `h`. But Ruby is object-oriented and everything is an object, and `h` is just a reference (an object-pointer). And nothing prevents you from modifying the object to which `h` points.

Comment: … except the object itself, if it wants to. E.g. `Symbol`s, `Integer`s, `true`, `false`, `nil`, and starting with Ruby 3 `String`s.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Ruby 3 (documentation links please) :)

Comment: @engineersmnky: https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/11473 The first phases have already been started in Ruby 2.2 ("magic" `'string'.freeze`) and Ruby 2.3 (frozen string literals).

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on @Sergio's comment, the reason you can change `@h` is because `attr_reader :h` is shorthand for:

```
def h
  @h
end
```

So defining this method has no bearing on what you can do to set the instance variable `@h`.